# Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy tratando de realizar un UPDATE involucrando a dos bases de datos distintas utilizando MySQL. La consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

```
    UPDATE sm4rtuniversity.members SET chamilo_id = (SELECT cu.id FROM chamilo.user cu
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members sm ON cu.email=sm.email);
```

Y al momento de ejecutarla me lanza el siguiente error: ***Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='***

Answer (score 2):

El error te informa que los campos que estás tratando de igualar, están definidos en distintos COLLATIONs, que son juegos de caracteres (si mal no recuerdo).

Te sugiero que agregues o fuerces el COLLATION de los campos que estás igualando, de modo que hablen el mismo idioma, como podría decirse. En tu caso, intentaré darte una idea modificando tu query, asumiendo que la tabla del UPDATE es la `utf8_unicode_ci` y la del SELECT la `utf8_spanish_ci`, pero eres tú quien tendrá que decidir dónde colocar los cambios, según tus especificaciones:

```
UPDATE sm4rtuniversity.members SET chamilo_id = (SELECT cu.id COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
FROM chamilo.user cu
INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members sm ON cu.email=sm.email);
```

[Investiga en este link más al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html)

> Por cierto, te falta un LIMIT 1 al final del SELECT para estar 100%
>   seguros que no te traerás más de un registro de la otra tabla.

Comment: Gracias por la edición, @Jack ^_^

Comment: Me han editado varias preguntas por motivos similares, la pregunta que tengo es la siguiente: ¿Esta mal decir por favor?